# Calculate Seasonal Cost in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am building an Access Database that needs to calculate the seasonal cost per night (based on hotel ID) and populate the entire cost for the date range in a query. Currently, all has to be calculated in sections and/or entered manually.

I have experimented with various tables and queries, but they all leave much to be entered by hand. I wanted to see if there is a way to completely automate this calculation, and any help would really be appreciated.

The table below shows a date range where one night costs $118 and the other is $159 for a total of $277. I would like to be able to run an automated query to populate total cost and cut out everything except check in and out dates (please excuse poor spacing, still figuring out formatting for posts on here.)

```
  ID | Hotel | CheckIn  | CheckOut | NumPeak | PeakCost | NumNonPeak | NonPeakCost | TotalCost

   1 | CILBV | 04/06/12 | 04/08/12 | 0000001 | $118.00  | 0000001    | $159.00     | $277.00
```

Comment: How is the seasonal cost calculated? If you cannot state how something is done manually, there is no way you can do it automatically. If I understand you correctly... you'll need to figure out what makes a date "peak" or "nonpeak". You should separate out the hotels and their costs in a separate table. Then you can track Hotel, CheckIn, CheckOut, (presumably guest or something), and everything else could be calculated. I recommend looking at a [tutorial on relational databases] (http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx) Link is old but relevant.

Comment: I was trying to keep the example as simple as possible in order to avoid confusion without an actual database to look at. I currently have a table for each hotel with a code for which seasonal rate to apply, with a query that multiplies the number of nights of each id by their proper rate. But this leaves me looking up date ranges every time I put in an entry. I was hoping there was a way to cut out the process of looking up date ranges - just automate the calculation as a whole.

Comment: Are you opposed to using VBA. That will probably be the easiest way for you to teach your database how to calculate the totals. You'd just need to provide the hotel code, start date, end date, and logic for figuring out if the date is seasonal or not. I could make you a skeleton of a possible solution following that path... but you'd need to fill in the details to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely be able to construct a single query that accepts check in + check out dates, and returns the the total cost.  The key piece of information is how much the hotel charges for every range of dates.

Let's say the table has columns like this (and if it's scattered across multiple tables, then you'll have to build a query with the appropriate inner join).

```
hotel_id    peak_start_date    peak_end_date    peak_price    non_peak_price
```

The tricky part is that there are a lot of possible scenarios:

1. start and end before *peak*
2. start before peak, end in peak
3. start before peak, end after peak
4. start in peak, end in peak
5. start in peak, end after peak
6. start after peak, end after peak

And that's just the cases where start + end dates are in the same year; there are six more scenarios for when the checkout is the following year.

So the question is how best to do the calculation, # of peak days and # of off peak days.  You could either:

1. construct a complex series of nested `IIF` statements
2. use a VBA method to perform the logic, pulling in the necessary info first from the table
3. some combination of 1 and 2

I'd probably go for #3, constructing a couple of simple helper queries, but putting the actual logic into a VBA method.

---

If you make an attempt and get stuck, you can always ask another question here (more specific questions tend to get better answers).